# VS Tests run multiple times instead of once

Tags: azure-devops, vstest

On Azure DevOps, from a couple of weeks, when I use Visual Studio Test task on a build definition, the tests are run multiple times (sometimes 2, 3, 5, ...): therefore, for example, I get 2500 tests executed instead of 1100 real ones.

Have you already met this issue? Is it a problem with the config of the task?

Comment: What does your test step look like? Are you excluding `obj` folders and other intermediary build folders, or otherwise scoping the search path so that it only finds one set of test assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're scoping your search path too broadly and it's picking up the same test assemblies multiple times.

Make sure your search path either excludes intermediary folders such as `obj`, or scope it to a specific output folder that you know contains all of your build outputs. `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` may fit the bill, depending on how your compilation is set up.